# Compile Error: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load an XML file, I'm using the XML 6.0 reference library.

The error occurs in the "xDom.load" line ( see below ). What can the issue be?

```
Private Sub run() ' run the whole operation

Dim http_req As http_req: Set http_req = New http_req
Dim xDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim url As String: url = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

Set xDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xDom.Load = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

Call find_ClassElement(xDom)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used msxml since I did a brief stint in Delphi, but I would imagine Load is method call. You are trying to set the reference of Load to a string. Try

```
xDom.Load("http://www.ecb........")
```